# How to report a bug of GoogleBot?

Tags: googlebot

Over the last days, Google Bot tries to read one URL of our main site over and over again, leading to a DDOS attack :) Our website got very slow because of the massive requests of the Google Crawler.

Here an excerpt for the curious ones (or if a Google engineers reads this post):

```
66.249.76.54 - - [27/May/2019:06:31:23 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/tag/594749/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/user/impressum HTTP/1.0" 200 32603
66.249.76.54 - - [27/May/2019:06:31:23 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/403551/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/bestusers HTTP/1.0" 200 32603
66.249.76.55 - - [27/May/2019:06:31:23 +0200] "GET /235432/tag/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/403551/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/403551/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/schreibregeln HTTP/1.0" 200 32603
66.249.76.54 - - [27/May/2019:06:31:23 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/594749/tag/chat HTTP/1.0" 200 32603
```

Or here (see the different IPs, so there are several bots):

```
66.249.76.54 - - [27/May/2019:09:24:42 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/386961/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/user/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/punkte HTTP/1.0" 200 32587
66.249.76.55 - - [27/May/2019:09:24:42 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/user/403551/agb HTTP/1.0" 200 32587
66.249.76.56 - - [27/May/2019:09:24:42 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/user/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/403551/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/qa-theme/lounge/js/lounge.min.js?v=2019-01-17 HTTP/1.0" 200 32587
66.249.76.55 - - [27/May/2019:09:24:42 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/594749/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/luckentext-zum-thema-extrema-funktionenschar-ft-x-1-2-tx-2-2-t HTTP/1.0" 200 32587
66.249.76.58 - - [27/May/2019:09:24:42 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/323274/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/tag/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/323274/user/Lu HTTP/1.0" 200 32587
66.249.76.57 - - [27/May/2019:09:24:42 +0200] "GET /235432/~plot~+4x%5E2%3B+4%2Ax%5E2+++4%2A%281/32%29%2Ax+-+15%2A%281/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/154807/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/323274/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/235432/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/32)*x%20-%2015*(1/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/user/user/tag/tag/~plot~%204x%5E2;%204*x%5E2%20+%204*(1/badges HTTP/1.0" 200 32587
```

The false link that was leading to this problem:

```
<a
href="~plot~ 4x^2; 4*x^2 + 4*(1/32)*x - 15*(1/32)^2; x; [[0.1]]~plot~" target="_blank">~plot~ 4x^2; 4*x^2 + 4*(1/32)*x - 15*(1/32)^2; x; [[0.1]]~plot~</a>
```

Where can I report a bug of GoogleBot?

There seems to be no official way how to report a bug.

Comment: Maybe these will help: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182072?hl=en

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708

Possibly just block GoogleBot from reading that one page, and/or put a limit on it.

Comment: Also found this article from 2015 that appears to still be relevant.  https://www.seroundtable.com/google-crawl-report-problem-19894.html

Comment: Thanks! I have written to their community at https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/6925026?hl=en Further, this link is about the crawl rate, but the crawl loop is my problem, so I do not apply it: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620

Comment: You shouldn’t use links like that but buttons instead. If you must though, mark the links with `rel=“nofollow”`. I believe this is a valid link a bot can follow, because it CAN point to a file named like that. Thus this isn’t a bug whatsoever

Comment: The bug is that GoogleBot tried to request it 1000s of times.

Comment: FYI: I prevented the bug with robots.txt adding `Disallow: /*~plot~`. Funny thing is that Google Webmaster Console shows 2.12M coverage issues now, all connected to the problem. Seems that Google bot did index the entire page with this weird ~plot~ fragment in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to report a crawling bug of Google Bot:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-report

> Report a problem with how Googlebot crawls your site.
>   You can report problems only for domain-level properties (for example, "www.example.com/")
>
> The rate at which Google crawls your page depends on many factors:
>
> The URLs we already know about
>   Links from other web pages (within your site and on other sites)
>   URLs listed in your Sitemap.
>   For most sites, Googlebot shouldn't access your site more than once every few seconds on average.

Probably the report link was not easy to find since you need a Google Webmaster account and can apparently only report your own websites.